# GridView children null for no reason

Tags: java, android, gridview

Basically, I have a GridView created in an alert dialog. I set an array adapter as normal, and it displays everything in the array as it should. However later on in the code, where I want to highlight a particular value in the GridView, by changing the background colour, it throws a null pointer exception. I know which line it is, however it should contain children, but doesn't.

GridView created like this:

```
GridView g = new GridView(this);

final ArrayAdapter<String> Wordadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.style,WordSearch);

String[] lag = WordSearch;
g.setId(2);
g.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
g.setHorizontalSpacing(-20);
g.setPadding(60,5, 10, 5);
g.setAdapter(Wordadapter);
g.setNumColumns(Length);
```

and I try to change the colour like this

```
for(int j = StartPosition; j  <= EndPos; j= j + Length) {
    g = (GridView) findViewById(2);
    g.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

The lines within the for loop throw the null pointer. When I checked the children on g, all the children (12) are null even though there are 121 elements in the array.

Start Position is 21, and end position is 109, and length is 15, so if the values were a problem, it wouldn't break on the first iteration.

Any ideas?

Extra code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// set title
aBuilder.setTitle("The solution");

GridView g = new GridView(this);

final ArrayAdapter<String> Wordadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.style,WordSearch);

String[] slag = WordSearch;
g.setId(1);
g.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
g.setHorizontalSpacing(-20);
g.setPadding(60,5, 10, 5);
g.setAdapter(Wordadapter);
g.setNumColumns(Length);

for(int i =0; i < Directions.length;i++) {
    int EndPos;
    int StartPosition = StartPos[i];
    int Direction = Directions[i];
    int Word = wordLengths[i];

    EndPos =  GetEndPosition(Direction,Word,StartPosition);

    int difference = StartPosition - EndPos;

    if ( Direction == 1)// direction down (1) {
        difference = difference  * -1;

        if( difference % Length == 0) {
            for(int j = StartPosition; j  <= EndPos; j= j + Length) {
                g = (GridView) Puzzle_Activity.this.findViewById(2);
                g.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `g.setId(1);` and then `g = (GridView) findViewById(2);`... Should be `findViewById(1);` You're giving it an id and then searching for a different one

Comment: Sorry, It's just a typo in the question, it overflows on the set background color, it's not the ID.

Comment: What are startPos, EndPos, and length?  getChildAt for a Gridview does not return the view for position n-  it returns the view for the nth item on screen.

Comment: theyre in the question Start Position is 21, and end position is 109, and length is 15,

Comment: without the for loop does your `GridView` display?

Comment: yeah, i think the problem is, Im doing all this calcualtions, before it's being drawn.

Comment: where are you performing this for loop?

Comment: Within an Alert Dialog Builder

Comment: can you show us the code.. you might be searching the dialog's view instead of the activity's views. Try  YourActivityName.this.findViewById(2) instead

Comment: Ill try that pal, added the code in the mean time though

Comment: You won't have any views at that point so that's why you're getting Null pointers. They have yet to be created or render

Comment: But surely, if i move it to below 
 aBuilder.create().show();
it would work? yet it still throws the same error

Comment: have you added the gridView to your activity view? as that is where you're trying to get it from.

Comment: If you mean the layout.xml file, No because i create it programatically

Answer (score 0):

The GridView recycles its childviews - so only the children that are currently visible are != null. So you can only change the views that are currently on the screen. The ones that go out at one end come back in at the other end, only their content changes. Thats for performance reasons when working with big datasets. You either tried to update the views to early (before they appeared) or at least one of them wasn't on the screen at the time you updated them. 
If you want to change views that are not on the screen, you should save that in  your backing model - for example some set with the marked words. And then mark the views as they come in. You need to write your Own Adapter for that - but thats rather easy.

You can access the view on the screen by doing something like this. Note that the first view visible is the view with index 0 - so you need to add the number of the first visible.

```
//Note that i find the grid before the loop since findViewById can be slow especially if you repeat them.
g = (GridView) findViewById(2);
int childcount = g.getChildCount();
int firstPos = g.getFirstVisiblePosition();

for ( int i = 0; i < childcount; i++ ) {
    int posInArray = firstpos + i;

    if (posInArray == whatEverYouWantedToMark)
    {
        g.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Honetly, all i need to do is get the grid view, I can display the grid then do the highlighting, thats not the issue, the issue is that it can't get my gridview  so the children are null